# c++, fastest way to check if a file exists?

Tags: c++, performance

There are multiple ways to check if a file exists.

The options I know of are:

1. `boost::filesystem exists()`
2. `access()`
3. `stat()`
4. `ifstream is_open()`

Does anybody know which of these gives the highest performance?

EDIT: Assume running on /dev/shm where access time is not a factor.

Comment: My bet is that they'd all be close the same. Since the run-time would be dominated by the seek latency of the HD or SSD.

Comment: Always profile under your conditions.  I could tell you what I think is fastest but you would have no idea if I just picked a random answer, or if the conditions I used to judge my answer are completely different from yours.

Comment: Let's assume running on /dev/shm in a Linux box, so not limited by access speed.

Comment: It's doubtful that there's a single option that is *always* the fastest in all situations.  The only way to answer this question is to compile your code using each option and measure the time it takes for each to run.

Comment: My bet would be on stat() since it is a system call.

Comment: What will you do next...read or write the same file that you look for?  If so, don't check first; *only do the read or write action*.  Existence checks prior to reads/writes are prone to race conditions (e.g. a file may seem to exist and then not actually be there when you go to open it, or vice-versa).  If the file is on a slow access point such as a network then you'll needlessly pay twice: once to go to the device to look for the file, and again when you actually try to write to it.  (An open-for-read might also have a penalty, but maybe not if there is caching in the system.)

Comment: I want to lock it afterwards using boost::filesystem file_lock() which throws an exception if you try to lock a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: So lock it and handle the exception. What if the file disappears between the time you check its existence and the time you try to acquire the lock? (It can happen even if they're adjacent statements in your program!) You have to be ready to handle the exception *anyway*, so you amy as well keep your program simple and not worry about special cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime here will be dominated by the switch into kernel mode and operation of the filesystem driver- even ignoring disk time. It's highly unlikely that any of them will offer superior performance. Best to pick the one which offers the best interface- `boost::filesystem`.

Answer (score 2):

**Modern C++ | Update**

C++17 provides this std function:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path FullPath("C:\\Test.txt");

    bool bExists = std::filesystem::exists(FullPath);
}
```